# Solve for n in Compound Interest Formula

Tags: finance

I would like to solve the compound interest formula 
$$V = Pz^n + c\left(\frac{z^{n+1}-z}{z-1}\right)$$
for $n$. Or, given what I would like the final value to be, the amount I can save a year, an interest rate, and how much money I have to invest initially, I would like to find how long it would take to reach my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:
\begin{align*}
V &= Pz^n + c\left(\frac{z^{n+1}-z}{z-1}\right)\\
V(z-1) &= Pz^n(z-1) + cz^{n+1} - cz\\
V(z-1) &= Pz^{n+1} - Pz^n + cz^{n+1} - cz\\
V(z-1) + cz &= z^n(Pz - P + cz)\\
\frac{V(z-1) + cz}{(P+c)z - P} &= z^n\\
\ln(V(z-1)+cz) - \ln((P+c)z - P) &= n\ln(z),
\end{align*}
so
$$n= \frac{\ln(V(z-1)+cz) - \ln((P+c)z-P)}{\ln z}.$$
You can use logarithms base 10 (or any base) if you prefer.